# Why doesn't estimating Shannon entropy with a histogram converge to its true value?

Tags: entropy, scipy

I'm following the third recipe of [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/313052/calculate-entropy-of-sample) to estimate the Shannon entropy of my samples using histograms.  My expectation was, increasing the sample size should lead to a better estimation of the *true* entropy. To test that, I sampled from a Gaussian distribution $N(0, \sigma^2)$ with [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information#Linear_correlation) entropy $H(X) = 0.5[1 + \log(2\pi \sigma^2)]$:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import entropy # by default in natural log
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sigma = 2
H0 = 0.5*(1 + np.log(2*np.pi*sigma**2)) # theoretical value in nats

Hs = []
ns = np.logspace(2,6,5, dtype=int)
for n in ns:
    X = np.random.normal(0, sigma, size=n)
    nbins = int(n/20)  # <--- This is causes divergence, read UPDATE 2
    hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(X, nbins, density=True)
    Hs.append(entropy(hist)) # will be automatically normalized to sum to 1

plt.plot(ns, Hs, '-x', label='estimation')
plt.hlines(H0, ns[0], ns[-1], linestyle='--', color='k', label='exact H')
plt.legend()
plt.yticks(np.arange(11))
plt.xscale('log')
plt.xlabel('num samples')
plt.ylabel('sample entropy')
```

To my surprise, they diverge:

[image]

Am I missing something very simple?

I found a [relevant question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395121/how-entropy-scales-with-sample-size) that is concerned about the case where the probability distribution is either "peaked" or "flat". The upshot of the most voted answer is that one has to normalize the entropy by $\log n$ where $n$ is the number of samples. Although I find this normalization sensible, I still observe an offset between the theoretical value and the estimation:

```py
plt.plot(ns, np.array(Hs)/np.log(ns), '-x', label='normalized estimation') # normalized
```

[image]

What causes this discrepancy?

As @sextus-empiricus noted below, scaling the number bins with the sample size leads to a coarse density estimation. In fact, **fixing the number of bins, resolves the divergence**. However, no matter what number of bins one chooses, there's still some offset between the estimated (normalized or non-normalized) entropy and the theoretical value, as you can see below:

[image]

What is the reason behind this gap? The curve displacement by `nbins` clearly suggest that there's a relationship between the two, but I found the reason elusive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an image that I made with the R-code below. The computation is with n-bins = 50.

There is in this simulation also an offset but smaller and with more bins I get a smaller offset. This might be because you approach the values of a discretized normal distribution and not the values of a continuous normal distribution. So one should not expect the same.

For small sample sizes there is lower entropy. This might be counter intuitive because one would imagine a small sample to be more variable and more chaotic. But, the state described by the histogram of a small sample is a very particular state and has *more* order than the average of many different samples. The increase of the sample size can be seen as blending multiple states and that creates an average that blends out to a smooth histogram, a histogram that looks like a more homogeneous sample.

[image: example simulation]

```
set.seed(1)
n_range = 10^seq(2,6,0.2)
entropy_range = c()
n_bins = 50

for (n in n_range) {
  x = rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 2)
  h = hist(x, breaks = n_bins, freq = 0)
  p = h$density[h$density > 0]
  bin_size = h$mids[2]-h$mids[1]
  entropy = -1*sum(log(p)*p*bin_size) 
  entropy_range = c(entropy_range, entropy)
}


plot(x= n_range, y= entropy_range, log = "x")
lines(x= c(1,10^6), y= c(1,1)*(0.5*log(8*pi)+0.5), lty = 2)
```

A tricky part is that the computation of entropy is different for continuous distributions

$$\int f(x) \log \left( f(x) \right) \text{d} x \approx \sum_{k = 1}^{n_{bins}} f_k \log \left( f_k \right) \cdot \text{bin_size}$$

When you just apply the bin probabilities $p_k = f_k \cdot \text{bin_size}$ and use the formula for discrete distributions then you get a different values.

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{n_{bins}} f_k \cdot \log \left( f_k \right) \cdot \text{bin_size} \neq \sum_{k = 1}^{n_{bins}} f_k \cdot \text{bin_size} \cdot  \log \left( f_k \cdot \text{bin_size} \right) = \sum_{k = 1}^{n_{bins}} p_k \cdot  \log \left( p_k \right)$$

You will be wrong with a factor $\log(\text{bin_size})$ and that explains the different curve displacements shown in your second edit.

In short: entropy is the expectation of the logarithm of the probability mass function or the probability density function $E[\log p(X)]$ and $E[\log f(X)]$. Problems arrise when we mix those formulas and functions.

Comment: That's right. Fixing the number of bins solves the problem of divergence. Yet, the offset persist. (I'll update my question to include this).

Comment: Thanks for posting this! I could reproduce your result once I set `nbins=20`, but not for other values of `nbins`. Please see my last figure, I just updated it. At this point, I'm not sure how `nbins` effects the gap between theoretical and estimated entropy values.

Comment: It is funny that in my previous version of the post I made the mistake discussed at the end, but because I used 20 bins which made binsizes of 1, it didn't make an influence. The weird discrete step that I observed there was due to the bin-sizes changing when the sample size increases.

Comment: Thank you very much for this update! Sure enough, adding $\log (\text{bin_size})$ fixes the gap.

Comment: @arash and the divergence that you had earlier was due to bin_size scaling with sample size. With the correct formula for entropy you can let the n_bins increase with n.